# Yii2 ajax validate and submit form

Tags: ajax, submit, yii2, form-submit, yii2-validation

I have very little AJAX's Information. That's why I asked my question here...

in yii2 how can create and submit form with ajax validation?

So I searched but could not find the right solution...

for example: (according to the official training site)

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
            'id' => $model->formName(),
            'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
]); ?>


<?= $form->field($model, 'title')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'extra_txt')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

and in controller:

```
    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        Yii::$app->response->format = 'json';
        return ActiveForm::validate($model);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
```

My problems:

1- ajax validation

2- submit form with ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use Pjax? Use yii\widgets\Pjax and add Pjax::begin() and Pjax::end() around your form.

A decent guide over here:
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/772/pjax-on-activeform-and-gridview-yii2/